# FastLanes. Run sh action in Xcode project root folder

Tags: ios, fastlane

Running `fastlane build_and_rename` on the following `Fastfile`,

```
  lane :build_and_rename do
    sigh
    gym(output_directory: "./Build/")
    sh "mv ./Build/MY-APP.ipa ./Build/nicely_name.ipa"
  end
```

results in the following error `ln: ./Build/MY-APP.ipa: No such file or directory`.

Testing shows that FastLane's `sh` action runs in the `./fastlane` directory. Example, `fastlane test_sh` for the following `Fastfile`

```
  lane :test_sh do
    sh "touch where_am_i.txt"
  end
```

results in a `where_am_i.txt` created in the `./fastlane` folder. Not in the folder where `fastlane` **was** run.

Obviously I could change all scripts to include `../` but wondering if there was a way to make `fastlane` run `sh` action in xCode's root project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out to be rather simple, just add `cd.. &&` to change to the root directory.

```
lane :test_sh do
    sh "cd .. && touch where_am_i.txt"
end
```

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/990#issuecomment

Comment: how to pass params in the shell script? This did not work `lane :addPrivateKey do | options |
  sh ("cd .. &&  ./add_key.sh ", options[:clientKey])
end`

Comment: What is the error? Have you you tried something like `sh ("touch", options[:clientKey])` to see if the options parameter is working as expected?

Comment: Try to pass parameters in this way `#{options[:pbxproj_path]}`

Answer (score 2):

To change the directory you can use Ruby, [Dir.chdir](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Dir.chdir)

**Example**

```
lane :test_sh do
  Dir.chdir("..") do
    # code here runs in the parent directory
    sh "touch where_am_i.txt"
  end    
end
```

See [Fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/fastlane/#directory-behavior)

Answer (score 1):

Calling fastlane action in shell script.

going to the folder that has fastlane folder.

path="path to fastlane"

```
cd $path/
fastlaneAction="fastlane test_do"
$fastlaneAction
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).